# Dynamically adding a list to an already existing set of lists after a user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html

I already have a set of clickable lists declared in an article in my HTML. I want a new clickable list to be added to that article when a user clicks my button and I want the data the user entered in to be the ID of the list (i.e if the user entered in Hello then the new lists href would be href="#Hello"). How can I do this?

This is my article in my HTML:

```
<article>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li><a href="#Tiger" onclick="myFnc('G. cuvier')">Tiger</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Hammerhead" onclick="myFnc('S. mokarran')">Hammerhead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Bull" onclick="myFnc('C. leucas')">Bull</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Great White" onclick="myFnc('C. carcharias')">Great White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Mako" onclick="myFnc('I. oxyrinchus')">Mako</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Greenland" onclick="myFnc('S. microcephalus')">Greenland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Whale" onclick="myFnc('R. typus')">Whale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Thresher" onclick="myFnc('A. vulpinus')">Thresher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Oceanic" onclick="myFnc('C. longimanus')">Oceanic WhiteTip</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Goblin" onclick="myFnc('M. owstoni')">Goblin</a></li>
        //if the user entered Hello I want the new list to look like this
          //<li><a href="#Hello" onclick="myFnc('Hello')">Hello</a></li>
        </ul> 
</article>
```

and here is my button in my HTML:

```
<input type="test" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: It seems like you want us to code for you. Did you actually try to do something yourself?

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I've tried many things but I have not been able to find anything that works. I believe Javascript is the only way I could possibly achieve what I'm looking for though.

Comment: So you want to append a new list item which contains a anchor tag to display the word entered but also with a `onclick` attribute to execute `myFnc()` with the argument of the word entered..... So what have you tried to accomplish this and what appears to be the problem?

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to do it for me I just can't figure out how I can dynamically add a new list

Comment: @HunterDavis Research `javascript append` I'm sure you will find many results how to create/add/append new elements.

Comment: I've tried doing it with PHP because I'm really trying to send the data to my database however after that didn't work out I figured I would try to start out simple and take it from there which is why I asked this question

Comment: Well I have just told you what to search up on but using `javascript` to append new elements does not mean those elements will be saved. Once the page has been reloaded/refreshed any memory of changes will be lost. Maybe if you use `AJAX` to send the data to a `php` file and append them depending on the `ajax` response would be a better method. This would all depends on how you are using `php` to output the elements on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `append` the `li` element dynamicaly to `ul`  on `click` of button.

Here are the steps you have to do:

**STEP-1.** Bind the `click event` on button.

**STEP-2.** Set any `id` or `class` on `ul` for using selector(I have set the id="list" in demo).

**STEP-3.** `OnClick` of button get the `value` of `input`.

**STEP-4.** Get the ul element by `id`(or by `class`).

**STEP-5.** Dynamically create `li` and `a` element and append to `ul`.

**Here is the working snippet that can help you:**

```js
document.getElementById("btnName").addEventListener("click", addNewLi);

function addNewLi(){
var inputVal=document.getElementById("inputName").value;
console.log(inputVal);
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(inputVal);
      // new code here
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('href', '#'+inputVal);
        a.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFnc("' + inputVal + '")');
        a.appendChild(text );
        li.appendChild( a );
        ul.appendChild(li);
     
}
```

```html
<article>
        <ul id="list" style="list-style-type:none">
            <li><a href="#Tiger" onclick="myFnc('G. cuvier')">Tiger</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Hammerhead" onclick="myFnc('S. mokarran')">Hammerhead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Bull" onclick="myFnc('C. leucas')">Bull</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Great White" onclick="myFnc('C. carcharias')">Great White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Mako" onclick="myFnc('I. oxyrinchus')">Mako</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Greenland" onclick="myFnc('S. microcephalus')">Greenland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Whale" onclick="myFnc('R. typus')">Whale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Thresher" onclick="myFnc('A. vulpinus')">Thresher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Oceanic" onclick="myFnc('C. longimanus')">Oceanic WhiteTip</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Goblin" onclick="myFnc('M. owstoni')">Goblin</a></li>
        //if the user entered Hello I want the new list to look like this
          //<li><a href="#Hello" onclick="myFnc('Hello')">Hello</a></li>
        </ul> 
</article>

<input type="text" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the click event function `myFnc()` on the `ul` element instead of each li element. You can check out the working code for the reference below.

```
<input type="test" id="inputName" />
    <button id="btnName" onclick="addToList()">Click me!</button>
    <article>
       <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="listWrap" onclick="myFnc()">
       </ul>
    </article>
    <script>
       function addToList(){
         var input = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
         document.getElementById('inputName').value = "";
         var listWrapper = document.getElementById('listWrap');
         var li = document.createElement("li");
         var a = document.createElement("a");
         a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
         a.setAttribute("href", "#"+input);
         li.appendChild(a);
         listWrapper.appendChild(li);
       }
    </script>
```